Settimeout if no response from the api call
I want to set a timeout locally if there is no response from the api call, and cancel the call if no response after i.e 10 seconds. How can this be done using settimout method or promise? Example(with mistakes):
const func() = await fetch(api)  // Here `fetch` is used for example, I am asking the question as general fetching operations from db, or firebase
setTimeout(()=>{
    cancelFunc()  // if no response after 10 seconds
},10000)


Does this help? Is there a way to short circuit async/await flow?

Source
async function fetchWithTimeout(api) {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(api, {
            signal: AbortSignal.timeout(10000) // timeout
        })
        const data = await response.json()
        return data
    } catch (error) {
        // Timeouts if the request takes
        // longer than 10 seconds
    }
}


Can you relook at the edited post? The fetch is used for generalizing the question, I need to use some db functions using firebase

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
